# count sql query used in rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How to use count query in rails 4. I try to use , but I get

```
undefined method `where' for 57:Fixnum
```

my sample code is,

```
 @empcount = Employee.count("emp_name")
                       .where("org_id = ? ", current_user.org_id)
```

What is the error with that?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, you try to call `where` on the result of `call`, which is `Integer`.

Comment: sorry I cant get idea. can u please explain in detail. I dont know sql in full.

Comment: @MarekLipka: you mean, "result of `count`"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, of course, unfortunately I can't edit my comment anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Employee.count("emp_name")` would return the total count of the `employees.emp_name`. A logical re-ordering of your query should return the result you're looking for:

```
@empcount = Employee.where("org_id = ? ", current_user.org_id).count("emp_name")
```

Comment: Yep, this is most likely what he's after.

Comment: Thanks to all active responses. I did a misplacement of where and count.This is damn blind error. Really thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this of any use?

```
@empcount = Employee.where(org_id: current_user.org_id).count
```

You need to find all employees by `org_id` and then do a count on all rows returned, right?

Comment: `find_by` returns one record

Comment: Do you know what `find_by` will return? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Comment: Excuse me, new to Ruby. Didn't notice the difference. Will correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `.where` on integer value returned by `count`

Change your query to:

```
@empcount = Employee.where(org_id: current_user.org_id).count
```

Comment: Thanks @deepak..:)